# ggplot not drawing connection lines between group means any more?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I seem to have missed a change within how ggplot2 works. I have an example from a statistics textbook (A. Field (2012), Discovering statistics using R, p. 593) which I'm sure worked but now does not produce connection lines between means of grouped data any more.

Here's the sample data:

```
participant<-gl(20, 9, labels = c("P01", "P02", "P03", "P04", "P05", "P06", "P07", "P08", "P09", "P10", "P11", "P12", "P13", "P14", "P15", "P16", "P17", "P18", "P19", "P20" ))
drink<-gl(3, 3, 180, labels = c("Beer", "Wine", "Water"))
imagery<-gl(3, 1, 180, labels = c("Positive", "Negative", "Neutral"))
groups<-gl(9, 1, 180, labels = c("beerpos", "beerneg", "beerneut", "winepos", "wineneg", "wineneut", "waterpos", "waterneg", "waterneut"))
attitude<-c(1, 6, 5, 38, -5, 4, 10, -14, -2, 26, 27, 27, 23, -15, 14, 21, -6, 0, 1, -19, -10, 28, -13, 13, 33, -2, 9, 7, -18, 6, 26, -16, 19, 23, -17, 5, 22, -8, 4, 34, -23, 14, 21, -19, 0, 30, -6, 3, 32, -22, 21, 17, -11, 4, 40, -6, 0, 24, -9, 19, 15, -10, 2, 15, -9, 4, 29, -18, 7, 13, -17, 8, 20, -17, 9, 30, -17, 12, 16, -4, 10, 9, -12, -5, 24, -15, 18, 17, -4, 8, 14, -11, 7, 34, -14, 20, 19, -1, 12, 43, 30, 8, 20, -12, 4, 9, -10, -13, 15, -6, 13, 23, -15, 15, 29, -1, 10, 15, 15, 12, 20, -15, 6, 6, -16, 1, 40, 30, 19, 28, -4, 0, 20, -10, 2, 8, 12, 8, 11, -2, 6, 27, 5, -5, 17, 17, 15, 17, -6, 6, 9, -6, -13, 30, 21, 21, 15, -2, 16, 19, -20, 3, 34, 23, 28, 27, -7, 7, 12, -12, 2, 34, 20, 26, 24, -10, 12, 12, -9, 4)

longAttitude<-data.frame(participant, drink, imagery, groups, attitude)
```

And here's the plot code:

```
library(ggplot2)
attitudeInt <- ggplot(longAttitude, aes(drink, attitude, colour = imagery))
attitudeInt + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") + 
              stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", aes(group = imagery)) + 
              stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) + 
              labs(x = "Type of Drink", y = "Mean Attitude", colour = "Type of Imagery")
```

Isn't it the case that the part `stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="line", aes(group = imagery))` should draw exactly these connection lines?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Works for me. What version of R and ggplot2 are you using? Also, try restarting R into a clean session and trying again.

Comment: @joran this doesn't work for me too. ggplot2_0.9.3

Comment: @agstudy I'm still on 9.2.1, so that might be part of the problem.

Comment: For the curious: The warning is `geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`.

Comment: turning options(error=recover/browser) doesn't work..I give up!

Comment: I upgraded to 0.9.3 and it still works fine for me. Curious.

Comment: This is a bug: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/739 which was introduced fixing another bug. Effectively, `stat_summary` now overrides the `group` aesthetic to include the `x` aesthetic, which then does not allow lines to be drawn between categorical `x` values.

Comment: Im using ggplot2_0.9.3 as well. @Brian Diggs Is there a workaround for this?/What can I do?

Comment: @absurd Not directly that I know of. Other than summarizing the data outside of ggplot and using that.

Comment: @BrianDiggs The bug only appeared for me when I also updated plyr to 1.8, interestingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will not solve the problem in `ggplot2` but this is workaround.

First summarize your data. As in original code you used `mean_cl_boot` for calculating confidence intervals, then used also in this example.

```
library(plyr)
dfAtt<-ddply(longAttitude,~drink+imagery,function(x) mean_cl_boot(x$attitude))

dfAtt
  drink  imagery      y      ymin     ymax
1  Beer Positive  21.05  15.65000 26.90750
2  Beer Negative   4.45  -2.60125 12.00000
3  Beer  Neutral  10.00   5.49750 14.75000
4  Wine Positive  25.35  22.40000 28.25000
5  Wine Negative -12.00 -14.40000 -9.49875
6  Wine  Neutral  11.65   8.95000 14.40125
7 Water Positive  17.40  14.40000 20.45000
8 Water Negative  -9.20 -12.25000 -6.34875
9 Water  Neutral   2.35  -0.75125  4.90000
```

Then plot your data:

```
ggplot(dfAtt, aes(x=drink, y=y, colour=imagery,group=imagery)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), width=.2) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Type of Drink", y = "Mean Attitude", colour = "Type of Imagery")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. This solution separates calculations and plotting. This makes the code even more readable. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As [Brian Diggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892313/brian-diggs) pointed out, this is a [known bug](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/739), that [has been fixed](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/739#ref-commit-deb4c50), recently. Thus, upgrading ggplot2 to 0.9.3.1 or above should bring the proper line drawing behaviour in stat_summary back.